# The closure of two languages

Tags: automata

From Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation (2nd Edition):

"For a final example, the closure of the empty set = { epsilon } where epsilon is the empty string.  Empty set is one of only two languages whose closure is
not infinite."  What is the other language?

Comment: Oh I see, it would have to be { epsilon }.

Answer (score 0):

The Kleene closure is an idempotent operator: given a language $L$, it holds $(L^*)^*=L^*$. So another such language is...

For the converse, suppose $\sigma\in L$ and $\sigma\ne\epsilon$. Then $\{\sigma,\sigma\sigma,\sigma\sigma\sigma,\cdots\}\subseteq L^*$ and all those strings are distinct, because they have strictly increasing length.

Comment: You mean Kleene closure, right?

Comment: @uwe Indeed${}$.